# What is dist[i][i] in Floyd–Warshall

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

So in the Floyd–Warshall algorithm, it will calculate all shortest paths in a weighted graph with positive or negative edge weights. I know that dist[i][j] is the closest distance from i to j node.

My question is when we run the algorithm from wiki, (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm), what is the value dist[i][i]? is that the shortest cycle that goes through i? Or what does that value mean?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct. If edge weights are positive $d(i, i)$ will be $0$, whereas if edge weights are allowed to be negative there might exist a cycle of negative length through $i$; in the latter case the algorithm will return the length of the shortest **simple** cycle through $i$ (note however that the distance between $i$ and itself should be $-\infty$, as explained by wikipedia).

Comment: Thank for your answer. But I dont get what do you mean by "note however that the distance between i and itself should be −∞, as explained by wikipedia" ? So when the algorithm ends, the dist[i][i] is not actually the length of the simply cycle that goes through i? Thanks

Comment: If you have a cycle with negative length, then you can keep looping around it to obtain a cycle of arbitarily small length (that's what I meant by $-\infty$). The algorithm computes the length of the shortest simple cycle through $i$, but not the length of the shortest (non-simple) cycle.