# Loops in Floyd-Warshall algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Possible duplicate: [What is dist[i][i] in Floyd–Warshall](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693398/what-is-distii-in-floyd-warshall)
My question is in Floyd-Warshall we change the diagonal values 0 to infinity. what will be the final diagonal values?

I know that Floyd-Warshall algorithm can be used to solve the all-pairs shortest paths problem and also can be used to detect negative cycles. I m finding it hard to tie it with the question above.

My intuition says it will stay as infinity but I think its wrong.

Comment: are paths allowed to be negative ? my guess is not since you put $dist[i][i]$=0 . anyway if you put diagonal values to infinity(+ I guess ) $dist[i][i]$ will stay infinite if node $i$ is not in a cycle (if there was a cycle containing $i$ there was a path from i to i and it will be smaller then infinity so value will be changed)

Comment: So the value will be changed to the min value of the cycle?

Comment: yes if i is in say 2 cycles dist[i][i] will be path length of "shorter" cycle, but I am not sure what problem are you trying to solve, you didn't say anything about weight of paths(edges) of your graph. If it was general question about algorithm you should draw small example and see what happens.